# How to use ngIfThen with ng-container

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, angular-ng-if

I'm building a simple rock, paper, scissors app. The moment I click a button (rock/paper/scissor), it will say: "You picked ... ". After that it should hide the other 2 buttons.

I want to go for the option to hide the whole ng-container. Is there a way I can hide the ng-container *after* clicking on one of the buttons? So add it in the *ngIfThen statement?

```
<div *ngIf="hand==='rock' then rockTemplate"></div>
<div *ngIf="hand==='paper' then paperTemplate"></div>
<div *ngIf="hand==='scissors' then scissorTemplate"></div>
<ng-template #rockTemplate>
  You picked: <app-rock></app-rock>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #paperTemplate>
  You picked: <app-paper></app-paper>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #scissorTemplate>
  You picked: <app-scissors></app-scissors>
</ng-template>


<ng-container #hideContainer class="board">
  <app-rock (click)="pickHand('rock')"></app-rock>
  <app-paper (click)="pickHand('paper')"></app-paper>
  <app-scissors (click)="pickHand('scissors')"></app-scissors>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simplify with `ng-switch`:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="hand">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="rock">You picked: <app-rock></app-rock></div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="paper">You picked: <app-paper></app-paper></div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="scissors">You picked: <app-scissors></app-scissors> 
</div>
<ng-container *ngIf="!hasSelection" class="board">
  <app-rock (click)="pickHand('rock')"></app-rock>
  <app-paper (click)="pickHand('paper')"></app-paper>
  <app-scissors (click)="pickHand('scissors')"></app-scissors>
</ng-container>


// In your component class
hasSelection: boolean;
hand: 'rock' | 'scissors' | 'paper';

// ...
pickHand(type: 'rock' | 'scissors' | 'paper') {
  this.hasSelection = true;
  this.hand = type;
}
```

With `ng-switch` your template looks much cleaner and easier to read. You can show/hide the `ng-container` through a boolean variable that gets toggled once the user selects one *hand* type.

I do not know your logic, but you have to re-enable the `ng-container`, if the user has the possibility to choose an *hand* again.

Comment: After changing the *ngSwitchCase expressions to strings, they worked like a charm